# Radiation Effects on Electronics

Tags: raspberry-pi, accelerometer, radiation, magnetometer

I'm developing a magnetic field sensing kit for a project. The kit contains sensors (specifically an accelerometer, a gyroscope, and a magnetometer) that will detect and measure magnetic fields, and my team plans for this kit to be placed in a location with high amounts of radiation, specifically neutron, alpha, and gamma radiation.

I'm really new to radiation effects, so I was wondering how does radiation cause strange behavior to occur in electronics, and which components are the most likely to be affected by radiation? Right now, I'm looking for sensors for the kit, and it's near impossible to find radiation-hardened sensors. Given my unfamiliarity with radiation, I'm trying to understand how it affects electronics so I can see if we need to purchase specialty components or if we can make do with just regular components.

EDIT: After speaking with my team, to be honest, we don't have a specific value on the intensity of the radiation to be expected. All I was told that the source will emit neutrons. Looking at what's available in terms of components, rad-hard components tend to be quite expensive and big, not in a small IC form factor, so I think I'll just have to go with a different solution.

Comment: I think you should start with estimating the spoken intensities...

Comment: All semi-conductor junctions are sensitive to light/radiation. How sensitive varies. But a transistor inside a chip will act like a photo-transistor if exposed to enough high energy particles/photons. If it's for a high radiation environment, you will likely need to add shielding. The sensor, which you may not be able to shield, since it needs to sense something, may be a trickier proposition.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks. I'll ask around and see what kind of intensity is to be expected.

Comment: Minimize the exposure.  Place the sensors on a separate unit that connects to the computer (the Pi) that is somewhere with better shielding.

Comment: I'd recommend that you study reports of placing electronics in orbit around the Earth, the sun, or else for for long-duration missions. This is a well-studied area, with good funding, though there always will be more research needed. For circuits like MCUs, though, you will want "large feature" designs. The larger the transistor, the better, for example. Low voltage operation is better than high voltage operation, if you have a choice, because high voltages can "follow" an event and cause cascading damages. Duplication and voting systems may help with CPUs and software.

Comment: In addition to knowing the intensity and type of radiation you will be dealing with, you also want to understand what sort of failure rates are acceptable.  Since radiation effects are statistical, the more failures you can accept, the more affordable of parts you can use.  The satellite community has a lot of experience with the case where failure is extremely expensive (like breaking a hundred-million dollar satellite).  Their parts are expensive.

Comment: Some kinds of [magnetometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer) do not use any electronic components in the sensor itself.  E.g., a flux-gate magnetometer is just some coils of wire wrapped around a ferrite core.  You might think about how, using the right sort of cabling, you might be able to locate the electronics package at some distance from the actual sensor.

Comment: @user101402: "radiation" is a very broad term (see picture in Tony Steward's answer). So what type of radiation are you dealing with?

Comment: @jameslarge Since most magnetometer ICs seem to contain some kind of amplifier or driver, regardless of technology, wouldn't they still be damaged due to radiation? I was looking at the DRV425 and the DRV5055 by TI, and their ICs contain amplifiers, integrators, and output drivers even though they're hall-effect and flux-gate magnetometers, so wouldn't they still get damaged?

Comment: @CortAmmon That's the issue I'm facing with my parts. All the magnetometer ICs don't seem to be radiation-hardened, and the magnetometers that are hardened against radiation seem to be large and very expensive. If finding such components prove to be too expensive, what can I do to shield them against radiation? A lead lined box seems to be step 1, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: @user101402 Based on the comments, step 1 is to determine what type of radiation you are subjecting your components to, what its intensity is, and what failure rates are acceptable.  You have noticed the key issue: if you just say "make me hardened against radiation!" without specifying further, the parts get very expensive because, generally speaking, parts that have to be subjected to radiation have a tendency to be highly critical items where very low failure rates are accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Energy levels are inverse to wavelength so shielding depends on both.  Start with energy specs and IO lines & electronics that need protection.

Are you planning any nuclear tests?
[image]

Each wavelength has different reactions to electronics including;
- ionization ( arc or dielectric breakdown)
- atomic displacement of SiO2
- nuclear reactions from trace nuclear atoms.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the picture. It does a good job simplifying how radiation penetrates materials. My team doesn't plan to do any nuclear tests. We're just attempting to measure the magnetic field around a source that emits a large amount of radiation.

Comment: The "funny" part not shown in in the picture above is that neutrons after passing all the outer layers will in turn create **gamma radiation** when getting absorbed. So the water should better be placed before the lead.

Comment: Yes the picture in effect shows eddy currents& skin depth and not pulse spreading something like a low pass filter.

Comment: Eddy currents and skin depth makes only sense for electromagnetic waves. Among the radiation types in this picture only X-ray and gamma is EM-radiation. Alpha, beta and neutron radiation are just flying particles (He-nuclei, electrons and neutrons); not EM waves.

Answer (score 2):

Semiconductors can be damaged/destroyed when exposed to radiation.

I worked at a particle accelerator facility (TRIUMF, Vancouver BC) and once installed a regulated power supply mounted in a steel box in the cyclotron vault - it failed in a fairly short time (a few weeks, if I recall correctly).  The radiation level in that area was sufficiently high that we were only permitted to work in there for under two hours a day, and that only after the cyclotron had been off for a week or more.

Comment: I read the main magnet current was regulated 1ppm for many decades. wow. I recall my electronics in Pickering 2ndary heat exchanger during maintenance was never reported to be an issue. But that's just heavy water.

Answer (score -1):

In September of 2016 I have designed and built a circuit to measure things for isotope production with a cyclotron. The radiation levels during isotope production are pretty high ( mostly neutrons, lethal for humans ), yet the electronics works without a problem. The circuit consists of op-amps, DACs and ADCs, a microcontroller and bunch of passive components - just ordinary parts, not radiation hardened. So, if radiation levels are comparable there should be no problem.

Comment: So no care to select ENIG ground shields or double shielded cables?

Comment: This is a) not an answer and b) grossly misleading. No details about flux, design methods, error tolerance etc.